# JSON_TABLE and CLOB > 32k

Tags: json, oracle, clob

I am trying to read in & parse some JSON code.  It is working in most cases, except when the JSON string is > 32k, then it does not import the JSON string.  I'm using the following code.  We are running Oracle 12c SE:

```
INSERT INTO json_in (clob_data)
VALUES (EMPTY_CLOB())
RETURN clob_data INTO l_clob;

l_bfile := BFILENAME('TEMP_DIRECTORY', 'json.txt');
DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);

DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE (
  DEST_LOB      => l_clob,
  SRC_BFILE     => l_bfile,
  AMOUNT        => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
  DEST_OFFSET   => l_dest_offset,
  SRC_OFFSET    => l_src_offset,
  BFILE_CSID    => l_bfile_csid,
  LANG_CONTEXT  => l_lang_context,
  WARNING       => l_warning);
DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(l_bfile);

SELECT clob_data 
INTO v_json_string
FROM json_in;

FOR data IN (SELECT cid,
                    ts_id,
                    group_id,
                    c_subject,
                    c_message
              FROM JSON_TABLE(v_json_string FORMAT JSON,'$[*]'
                    COLUMNS (
                       cid                  NUMBER          PATH '$.cid',
                       ts_id                NUMBER          PATH '$.ts_id',
                       group_id             NUMBER          PATH '$.group_id',
                       c_subject            VARCHAR2(300)   PATH '$.c_subject',
                       c_message            VARCHAR2(32000) PATH '$.c_message') LOOP

    INSERT INTO commentary (cid,
                            ts_id,
                            group_id,
                            c_subject,
                            c_message)
    VALUES (data.cid,
            data.ts_id,
            data.group_id,
            data.c_subject,
            data.c_message);
END LOOP;
```

Seems like the c_message is > 32000, so, not sure how to get it to handle larger values.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CLOB` that you have already read in.

Something like (untested):

```sql
DECLARE
  l_clob         CLOB;
  l_bfile        BFILE;
  l_dest_offset  INTEGER := 1;
  l_src_offset   INTEGER := 1;
  l_bfile_csid   INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID;
  l_lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
  l_warning      INTEGER;
BEGIN
  -- INSERT INTO json_in (clob_data)
  -- VALUES (EMPTY_CLOB())
  -- RETURN clob_data INTO l_clob;

  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_clob, FALSE);

  l_bfile := BFILENAME('TEMP_DIRECTORY', 'json.txt');
  DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);

  DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE (
    DEST_LOB      => l_clob,
    SRC_BFILE     => l_bfile,
    AMOUNT        => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
    DEST_OFFSET   => l_dest_offset,
    SRC_OFFSET    => l_src_offset,
    BFILE_CSID    => l_bfile_csid,
    LANG_CONTEXT  => l_lang_context,
    WARNING       => l_warning
  );

  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(l_bfile);

  INSERT INTO commentary (
    cid,
    ts_id,
    group_id,
    c_subject,
    c_message
  )
  SELECT cid,
         ts_id,
         group_id,
         c_subject,
         c_message
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           l_clob FORMAT JSON,
           '$[*]'
           COLUMNS (
             cid                  NUMBER        PATH '$.cid',
             ts_id                NUMBER        PATH '$.ts_id',
             group_id             NUMBER        PATH '$.group_id',
             c_subject            VARCHAR2(300) PATH '$.c_subject',
             c_message            CLOB          PATH '$.c_message'
           )
         );
END;
/
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `clob` is [not available](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-C7F19D36-1E75-4CB2-AE67-ADFBAD23CBC2) in 12c: `json_value_return_type = { VARCHAR2 [ ( size [BYTE | CHAR] ) ]
| NUMBER [ ( precision [, scale] ) ]
| DATE
| TIMESTAMP
| TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
| SDO_GEOMETRY
}`